# Elasticsearch Match Date Range or Number in Array

Tags: elasticsearch

My goal is to filter my records by date and a day of the week (Mo = 1, Tue = 2, Thu = 3, ..., Sun = 7). In this case, either the date or the weekday should match any of the days in the array. Or both, of course. I am new to Elasticsearch and seem to have a number of mistakes in my query. I documented everything here, as far as I got and hope for a couple of helpful insights. Thanks in advance.

**Current Mapping**

```
{
  "index":{
    "mappings":{
      "entity":{
        "_meta":{
           "model":"AppBundle\\Entity\\Entity"
        },
        "properties":{
          "subEntity":{
            "properties":{
              "date":{
                "type":"date",
                "format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "days":{
                "properties":{
                  "day":{
                    "type":"string"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Current Records**

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/index/_search?pretty=1'
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "index",
      "_type" : "entity",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "subEntity" : [ {
          "date" : "2016-09-20T00:00:00+02:00",
          "days" : [ ]
        }, {
          "date" : "2016-09-21T00:00:00+02:00",
          "days" : [ ]
        }, {
          "date" : "2016-09-22T00:00:00+02:00",
          "days" : [ {
            "day" : 4
          }, {
            "day" : 5
          }, {
            "day" : 6
          } ]
        }, {
          "date" : "2016-09-20T00:00:00+02:00",
          "days" : [ ]
        } ]
      }
    },
    [...]
  }
}
```

---

**Current Request**

```
{
  "query":{
    "should":{
      "filter":[ {
        "range":{
          "entity.subEntity.date":{
            "gte":"2016-09-20",
            "lte":"2016-09-21"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "term":{
          "entity.subEntity.days.day": 2
        }
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

**MySQL Equivalent**

```
SELECT entity
FROM entity
LEFT JOIN subEntity ON (subEntity.entity_id = entity.id)
LEFT JOIN day ON (day.subEntity_id = subEntity.id)
WHERE subEntity.date BETWEEN 2016-09-20 AND 2016-09-21
OR day = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query across properties of a sub-object within a document (where a document may have a collection of such sub-objects), you need to map `subEntity` as a [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html). In your example, since you are only looking for documents that are within the date range **or** match the day value, you can use an `object` mapping as have, but if you need to combine queries with an **and** operation, then you would need a `nested` type mapping. If you need to do this, it would make sense to map as a `nested` type. Additionally, since day is a numeric value, you should map it as a `byte`.

```
{
  "index":{
    "mappings":{
      "entity":{
        "_meta":{
           "model":"AppBundle\\Entity\\Entity"
        },
        "properties":{
          "subEntity":{
            "type": "nested",
            "properties":{
              "date":{
                "type":"date",
                "format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
              },
              "days":{
                "properties":{
                  "day":{
                    "type":"byte"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now that `subEntity` is mapped as a `nested` type, [a `nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) needs to be used to query against it, so the query becomes

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "subEntity.date": {
                        "gte": "2016-09-20",
                        "lte": "2016-09-21"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "subEntity.days.day": [
                        2
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "path": "subEntity"
    }
  }
}
```

Both queries are issued as `bool` filter queries as we don't need to calculate a relevancy score for either, we simply need to know if a document matches or not i.e. a simple yes/no answer. Warpping a query in a `bool` filter means that the query runs in a filter context.

Next, either query can match, so we add both as `should` clauses to an outer `bool` query.

As a complete example:

Create index and mapping

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/entities?pretty=true 
{
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_replicas": 0,
    "index.number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "entity": {
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "subEntity": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "date": {
              "type": "date"
            },
            "days": {
              "properties": {
                "day": {
                  "type": "short"
                }
              },
              "type": "object"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Bulk index four entities

```
POST http://localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty=true 
{"index":{"_index":"entities","_type":"entity","_id":"1"}}
{"subEntity":{"date":"2016-09-19T05:00:00+00:00"}}
{"index":{"_index":"entities","_type":"entity","_id":"2"}}
{"subEntity":{"date":"2016-09-20T05:00:00+00:00"}}
{"index":{"_index":"entities","_type":"entity","_id":"3"}}
{"subEntity":{"date":"2016-09-18T18:00:00+00:00","days":[{"day":2},{"day":5}]}}
{"index":{"_index":"entities","_type":"entity","_id":"4"}}
{"subEntity":{"date":"2016-09-18T18:00:00+00:00","days":[{"day":3},{"day":4}]}}
```

Issue the search query above

```
POST http://localhost:9200/entities/entity/_search?pretty=true 
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "subEntity.date": {
                        "gte": "2016-09-20",
                        "lte": "2016-09-21"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "subEntity.days.day": [
                        2
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "path": "subEntity"
    }
  }
}
```

We should only get back entities with ids 2 and 3; id 2 matches on date and id 3 matches on day

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "entities",
      "_type" : "entity",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 0.0,
      "_source" : {
        "subEntity" : {
          "date" : "2016-09-20T05:00:00+00:00"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "entities",
      "_type" : "entity",
      "_id" : "3",
      "_score" : 0.0,
      "_source" : {
        "subEntity" : {
          "date" : "2016-09-18T18:00:00+00:00",
          "days" : [ {
            "day" : 2
          }, {
            "day" : 5
          } ]
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Learned a lot already. The date part works splendid, the days part not so much yet, unfortunately. Executing it without the term-filter delivers me the expected result. With the term, however, it returns nothing. Does this have something to do with the fact that not just subEntity is a subEntity but that days is an entity as well? I have three entities. Entity -> SubEntity -> SubSubEntity (Here called days)

Comment: Incredible, that seems difficult yet reasonable - I will review it in just a few minutes when I'm back

Comment: Actually, you only need to combine queries with a `should` clause here, so an `object` mapping will work. But if you needed to do queries such as within a `date` range **and** a specific `day` value, then a `nested` type mapping would be needed,

Comment: I had to additionally specify the time_zone parameter in the range filter due to the way my dates were indexed, however, everything else works splendidly. Thank you so much. Already getting a much better grasp of Elasticsearch because of that.

Comment: @chrisp - no worries, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution can be easily achieved using "or" query but now in es 2.0.0 onwards "or" query is deprecated. in-place of using or query we can use "bool" query now. Sample query is given below

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool" : {

    "should" : [
            {
                 "term" : { "CREAT_DT": "2015-11-03T07:49:07.000Z" }
            },
            {
                "term" : { "TableName": "dwd" }
            }
        ],

        "minimum_should_match" : 1,
        "boost" : 1.0
    }
    }
}
```

More details about it's uses can be found in below link
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-bool-query.html